# Why can't I connect to my wireless router with my wireless adapter (Edimax EW‑7811Un)?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

This has me stumped. I simply want to use my Edimax EW‑7811Un (which I've used in multiple PCs) to connect to my wireless internet. If I have initial problems, I usually uninstall and reinstall drivers/update drivers, try different usb ports, etc. With all those checked off already, I'm out of ideas. Here's the real issue. I have installed the adapter's drivers and updated them. I get the signal bar that signifies that wireless connections are available. But when I click the "Connect" button for my (or any) wifi connection, the connections box disappears and it doesn't connect. It doesn't ask for a password or anything either. Double clicking the connection does the same. I've also tried resetting the wireless adapters and used the "ipconfig reset winsock" command in cmd. I have also tried connecting in safe mode, same thing happens. Can't decide if it's the adapter's fault or Windows'. I can confirm that the ethernet works fine, and wireless works fine on my laptop. Router has been rebooted and both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz are accessible. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I can confirm that it is not the adapter. I just used two other adapters of different brands and got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume other wireless devices are able to connect to the router and the internet.

Is it possible that you have MAC filtering enabled on the router?

Have you looked at your router log to see if the device is trying to connect and if so what the result is?

Comment: Yes all other wireless devices work fine. The MAC filtering is not enabled and log does not show this particular PC. As a side note, I'm unable to connect to ANY wireless devices (routers/other computers/printers). Trying only results in the same thing; no attempt to connect.